# Query should exclude headers

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get just one result from this query:

```
=QUERY('Registro Clinico'!A1:AA1000; "select A where(B='B12')")
```

where `B12` contains `17.555.829-2`.

I need it to return the ID of the patients, but it's returning the header name "ID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude headers by supplying `FALSE` for the `headers` parameter. ([Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343))

```js
=QUERY('Registro Clinico'!A1:AA1000; "select A where (E='"&B12&"')"; FALSE)
                                                                     ^^^^^
```

You had other problems as well:

- The Query language does not support references into the spreadsheet in the way you had tried to write it.

  ```js
  "...where (B='B12')..."
  ```

  Instead, you need to concatenate text segments using the `&` operator:

  ```js
  "...where (B='" & B12 & "')..."
                ^^^     ^^^
  ```
- The column in `'Registro Clinico'` that contains `17.555.829-2` is `E`, not `B`.

Comment: it shows "empty result" could you please help me?  [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOcSENpIh8AvAHk8riXUk2qnf-ktTux7K9mDKbe0tXw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well played Mogsdad.  Nice snipe.

Comment: I was curious about the contatenation, since the CONTATENATE function is cumbersome to use.  Also handy to use the header flag.

Comment: @eniacAvenger - It was a different answer, not a snipe. (You added the `headers` param to your answer [just before posting the snipe comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33267983/revisions) - so who is borrowing from whose answer?)

Comment: @Mogsdad - The root of the problem was not the header flag.  It was that the syntax was incorrect and that the wrong column was used in the where clause.  You are correct that I added the header flag later and contatenation syntax for a cleaner solution (thanks by the way for the recommendation). But in my experience, StackOverflow courtesy would be to add a comment to my answer about the flag and concatenation.  My answer was correct, but based on the new data that the user posted, I updated the query for column E.

Comment: @Mogsdad - That said, your answer does provide a lot of value with references to the Google documentation, and instructing the user where he went wrong.  So maybe I was out of line with the snipe comment, just sour grapes since I have a hard time building up my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
=QUERY('Registro Clinico'!A1:AA1000,"select A where E='" & 'Registro Clinico'!B12 & "'", FALSE)
```

Comment: B12 actually contains 17.555.829-2, i tried using both formulas but i got an error, "error analyzing the formula"

Comment: I updated the query slightly, needed to add 'Registro Clinico' reference to B12.  I just confirmed that it works in google spreadsheets.

Comment: it didn't really worked, could you please check my spreadsheet please? thanks :3 [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOcSENpIh8AvAHk8riXUk2qnf-ktTux7K9mDKbe0tXw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: =QUERY('Registro Clinico'!A2:AA1000,CONCATENATE("select A where E='",'Registro Clinico'!B12,"'"))

Comment: Make that =QUERY('Registro Clinico'!A1:AA1000,"select A where E='" & 'Registro Clinico'!B12 & "'", FALSE)